# ResultSet to JTable producing a boolean value on one of the columns

Tags: java, mysql, swing, boolean, jtable

I am retrieving data from MySQL database using result set. When the data is mapped to a `JTable`, one of the columns, the third, gives a Boolean output. I need the original integer values.

Here is the code:

```
int name = jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex();
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stm = null;
switch (name) { 

    case 0: {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/school", "root", "");
            stm = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from opener_out_of");
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            jTable2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OutOf.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        break;
    }
    case 1: {
        ................
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing what happens in the other parts of the `switch` statement, I can't really comment.  You can probably pull most of the JDBC code outside of the `switch` statement.  Add a problem statement to your question for best results here.

Comment: You need to show us the relevant code. That is most likely the DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs) part. The table structure of opener_out_of would help, too.

Comment: What is the type of the column and how is it managed in DbUtils, is it the one from Apache ?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to replace the DB.